# Delphi XE7- Convert memo to UTF8

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

How can I convert my memo.text to UTF-8 and sent it to my e-mail via TIdMessage component? I used this function but it does not work properly...

```pascal
function TForm1.EncodeAsUTF8(UnicodeStr: string): AnsiString;
var
  UTF8Str: UTF8String;
  i: Integer;
begin

  UTF8Str := UTF8String(UnicodeStr);

  SetLength(Result, Length(UTF8Str));

  for i := 1 to Length(UTF8Str) do
    Result[i] := AnsiChar(Ord(UTF8Str[i])); 

end;
```

Comment: Use `TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes()`. You don't store UTF8 in an `AnsiString`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but it still does not work. I have memo field where one of the values is '' Kontož'' and when I send that string to my e-mail I receive it as ''Konto??''.

Comment: @Pekkala that is partly because the RTL doesn’t know your `AnsiString` is UTF-8 encoded, so bad conversions are performed when it is assigned to other strings, like in your email code. But why are you using a UTF-8 encoded `AnsiString` at all? Why isn’t your email code taking normal `string`s and handing the conversion to UTF-8 when preparing the email’s raw bytes for transmission?

Comment: `TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes()` works. What doesn't work is what you do next with it. Which we don't know. You talk about sending string to email. We have no clue about that.

Comment: I also remember Lazarus tag because that doesn't tally with Delphi XE7. Try to be precise about your tagging.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I wrote this 
MailMessage.Body.Text := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(memo1.Text) 
and still the same problem appears.

Comment: We have no idea what `MailMessage` is. Try to imagine that we cannot see your screen.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry about that, the MailMessage is the name of  TIdMessage component which I use to create my message. I need to send values from my Dataset, over the memo, to an e-mail adress.

Comment: These details should be in the question. Please edit the question to include them. You should also complete the [tour]. It will help you get the most out of this site.

Comment: @Pekkala I updated my answer. You don't need to encode the UTF-8 manually at all. Indy handles it for you.

Answer (score 3):

Your function is not letting the RTL know that the `AnsiString` is UTF-8 encoded. Thus data loss *may* occur when the `AnsiString` is assigned to other strings after the function exits.

If you absolutely need to return a UTF-8 encoded `AnsiString` (which I do not recommend), then you have to ensure its metadata states the characters are using UTF-8, eg:

```pascal
function TForm1.EncodeAsUTF8(UnicodeStr: string): AnsiString;
var
  UTF8Str: UTF8String;
begin
  UTF8Str := UTF8String(UnicodeStr);
  SetString(Result, PAnsiChar(UTF8Str), Length(UTF8Str));
  SetCodePage(PRawByteString(@Result)^, CP_UTF8, False);
end;
```

Alternatively:

```pascal
function TForm1.EncodeAsUTF8(UnicodeStr: string): AnsiString;
begin
  PUTF8String(@Result)^ := UnicodeStr;
end;
```

However, it would be much simpler to just return a `UTF8String` instead and let the RTL handle the UTF-8 for you, eg:

```pascal
function TForm1.EncodeAsUTF8(UnicodeStr: string): UTF8String;
begin
  Result := UnicodeStr;
end;
```

Or, at least return a UTF-8 encoded `RawByteString` instead, eg:

```pascal
function TForm1.EncodeAsUTF8(UnicodeStr: string): RawByteString;
begin
  Result := UTF8String(UnicodeStr);
end;
```

---

**UPDATE**: That being said, `TIdMessage` is an Indy component, and Indy operates on normal `String` values.  In Unicode versions of Delphi (and FPC), Indy will handle the UTF-8 encoding for you when preparing the email for transmission.  Simply set the `TIdMessage.Body` to hold your Memo's normal Unicode text, and set the `TIdMessage.CharSet` to `'utf-8'`, eg:

```pascal
MailMessage.Body := Memo.Lines;
// or: MailMessage.Body.Text := Memo.Text;
MailMessage.CharSet := 'utf-8';
```

That is all you need. You don't have to encode the Memo text to UTF-8 manually at all.

Only in non-Unicode versions of Delphi (and FPC) would it make sense to use your `EncodeAsUTF8()` function.  The `TIdMessage.CharSet` property would still need to be set so the email headers claim UTF-8, but Indy will send the `AnsiString` bytes as-is and not re-encode them, so you would be responsible for ensuring the `AnsiString` is using UTF-8, eg:

```pascal
function TForm1.EncodeAsUTF8(UnicodeStr: string): AnsiString;
begin
  Result := UTF8Encode(UnicodeStr);
end;

...

MailMessage.Body.Text := EncodeAsUTF8(Memo.Text);
MailMessage.CharSet := 'utf-8';
```